# UIImageView re-size and rotate UIImageView at same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autoresize, autorotate

I have an UIImageView in my UIViewController. I set an image on it. I have done rotation doing as below.

```
- (void) runSpinAnimationOnView:(UIImageView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration rotations:(CGFloat)rotations repeat:(float)repeat
{
    CABasicAnimation* rotationAnimation;
    rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
    rotationAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: M_PI * 2.0 /* full rotation*/ * rotations * duration ];
    rotationAnimation.duration = duration;
    rotationAnimation.cumulative = YES;
    rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];

}
```

I call it as

```
[self runSpinAnimationOnView:_imageView duration:1.0 rotations:360 repeat:1.0];
```

Now I also want to resize same image view but with equal proportion from all sides, How can I do so.

Simply, I want to rotate an **UIImageView** and resize it simultaneously.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**CGAffineTransformConcat** will do your purpose, which will combine two transform into one & makes as single animation. try this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 3.0f
                      delay: 0
                    options: (UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{

                     UIView *yourViewToBeAnimated = YourViewToBeSetHere;

                     CGAffineTransform animationToRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);

                     CGAffineTransform animationToScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);//Double the size


                     yourViewToBeAnimated.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(animationToScale, animationToRotate);


                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {




                 }
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more than one animation to the layer. Just add `@"transform.scale"` animation as well

```
- (void) runScaleAnimationOnView:(UIImageView*)view duration:(CGFloat)duration scale:(CGFloat)scale repeat:(float)repeat
{
    CABasicAnimation* scaleAnimation;
    scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: scale];
    scaleAnimation.duration = duration;
    scaleAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;

    [view.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"scaleAnimation"];
}

[self runSpinAnimationOnView:_imageView duration:1.0 rotations:360 repeat:1.0];
[self runScaleAnimationOnView:_imageView duration:1.0 scale:0.5 repeat:1.0];
```

Notice that you may need to adjust `@"position"` as well

Answer (score 0):

Simply do it like this, you can make CGRectMake proportionally, as you want. its just way to show how will it resize.

```
- (void)rotateSpinningView
    {

        _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(_imageView.frame.origin.x+5,
                                      _imageView.frame.origin.y+5,
                                      _imageView.frame.size.width-10,
                                      _imageView.frame.size.height-10);

        _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        _imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
            [_imageView setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(_imageView.transform, M_PI_2)];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished && !CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(_imageView.transform, CGAffineTransformIdentity)) {
                [self rotateSpinningView];
            }
        }];
    }

    - (IBAction)changeView:(UIButton *)sender {

        [self rotateSpinningView];

    }
```

Comment: it correctly work for M_PI,M_PI_2 , not for 10,20,45 something like that